# Azure search - Import data which is in .md file

Tags: azure, postman, azure-cosmosdb, data-manipulation, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to upload data using postman and getting an error: "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."

I'm using the postman with:

```
url : https://azuresearchpocxxxx.search.windows.net/indexes/beers/docs/index?api-version=2017-11-11

request type : POST 
content-type : text/plain
```

The data was in the .md file:

```
| ID | Name                      | ActivelyBrewed | IBU | ABV  | Flavors | LastTappedOn | BreweryId | BreweryName                |
|----|---------------------------|----------------|-----|------|------------------------------|--------------|-----------|----------------------------|
| 1  | Ahool Ale                 | true           | 33  | 5.4  | biscuity                     | 1/23/2016    | b3TplPdS  | Northern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 2  | Agogwe Ale                | true           | 28  | 2.9  | wheat, floral                | 5/18/2016    | Ek4mwsBoe | Southern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 3  | Aswang Ale                | true           | 31  | 4.2  | butter, yeast                | 2/13/2016    | b3TplPdS  | Northern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 4  | Buru's Barley Wine        | true           | 76  | 11.1 | raisin, dried fruit, bourbon | 1/1/2016     | b3TplPdS  | Northern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 7  | Hyote Chocolate Stout     | true           | 78  | 7.4  | caramel, chocolate           | 1/7/2016     | zkXBTiBol | North American Brewco      | 
| 8  | Igopogo Pilsner           | true           | 36  | 5.7  | malt, bread                  | 11/15/2015   | zkXBTiBol | North American Brewco      | 
| 9  | Jackalobe Lager           | true           | 29  | 3.3  | fruit, citrus                | 3/15/2016    | zkXBTiBol | North American Brewco      |
| 11 | Mahamba Barley Wine       | true           | 57  | 9.7  | malt, raisin                 | 4/24/2016    | Ek4mwsBoe | Southern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 12 | Megalodon Pale Ale        | true           | 99  | 5.7  | bread, hops, pine            | 3/31/2016    | VkNvPjBse | Oceanic Brewco             |
| 16 | Pope Lick Porter          | true           | 39  | 6.5  | smokey, chocolate, banana    | 1/6/2016     | zkXBTiBol | North American Brewco      |
| 17 | Chocolate Pukwudgie Stout | true           | 35  | 12.2 | chocolate, coffee            | 2/25/2016    | zkXBTiBol | North American Brewco      |
| 18 | Sharlie Pilsner           | true           | 31  | 4.1  | grass                        | 2/18/2016    | zkXBTiBol | North American Brewco      |
| 19 | Sigbin Stout              | false          | 65  | 8.1  | coffee, caramel              | 3/18/2016    | b3TplPdS  | Northern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 21 | Snallygaster Pale Ale     | false          | 89  | 9.7  | pine, honey                  | 4/29/2016    | zkXBTiBol | North American Brewco      |
| 22 | Tikibalang Barley Wine    | true           | 45  | 9.6  | bourbon                      | 3/14/2016    | b3TplPdS  | Northern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 26 | Pale Popobawa Ale         | true           | 30  | 4.4  | wheat                        | 5/9/2016     | Ek4mwsBoe | Southern Hemisphere Brewco |
| 27 | North Adjule Lager        | true           | 30  | 3.7  | citrus                       | 2/8/2016     | Ek4mwsBoe | Southern Hemisphere Brewco |
```

I have already created an index and the field to hold data of this type.

I tried using the Import data option from the Azure portal(It doesn't have the option to select .md file)

Any thoughts on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here: import your data as a "delimited text" file or upload your data line by line.

**Option 1 ("delimited text" file)**

1. Upload your file into [blob storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/)
2. "Import data" from the portal, with a "Azure Blob Storage" data source (and "**Default**" parsing mode if you're creating a new data source)
3. Edit your index to contain the fields you care about
4. In the indexer tab, expand the "Advanced options" section and select **"Delimited text" parsing mode**, check **"First Line Contains Header"**, and set **delimiter character as "|"**

Equivalently, you can do everything using the REST APIs ([Data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source), [Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index), [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer)). The indexer will try to index the second line that doesn't contain any real data, which may be acceptable depending on your use case.

*You might need to set "**Max failed items**" to not fail on the second line.*

**Option 2 (POST to index)**

Use the [Add Document REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) for each line of your md file with the **@search.action set to "mergeOrUpload"**. The **content-type must be "application/json"** and you need to generate a JSON body with all the key-value pairs from your data.

---

If your data will be updated then you should go with **Option 1** and set your indexer on a schedule, so changes will be automatically picked up.